# Facebook authenticated referrals is not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, authorization

I have a problem with the authenticated referrals in the Auth Dialog. When a user uses the app for the first time and is requesting authorization, he/she gets "The App will receive: Your basic data." which is different from what is displayed when I preview the Auth Dialog in Facebook developer Apps site. I use the following code:

```
<script>
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));

// Init the SDK upon load
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
  appId      : '<%= Facebook::APP_ID %>', // App ID
  channelUrl : '//'+window.location.hostname+'/channel', // Path to your Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});

url = '<%= users_path %>'
// listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
 if (response.authResponse) {
  // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
  FB.api('/me', function(me){
    if (me.name) {
      window.open(url);
    }
  })
} else {
  // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
  document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
}
```

});

```
// respond to clicks on the login and logout links
document.getElementById('auth-loginlink').addEventListener('click', function(){
FB.login();
```

});

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replaced FB.login() with

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope : 'user_likes'});  });
```